# Easy way to know the backing type for dtypes in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a complex dataframe with columns of many dtypes, including categorials of multiple sizes. Is there a quick expression that ouputs the backing (numpy) dtype for all these columns? For example, this means that for a categorical column, it would output something like *int8*, *int16*, etc. depending on what's being used under the hood.

I already know about the `.dtypes` property of dataframes, but that doesn't do what I want, because it prints out `category` for every categorical, instead of printing something that reflects the type used to represent that particular categorical (which can be 1, 2, or 4 bytes).

For example, for this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': pd.Categorical(['a', 'b', 'c'])})
```

the function I'm looking for would output something that says that column *cat* ends up being represented in memory by an array of 1 byte numbers.

It's not hard to write a function that does that, but maybe there's an easy, one-line way to do this (that I couldn't find). Thanks!

Comment: `df.info()` will that work?

Comment: @ScottBoston No. For a column with pd.Categorical['a', 'b']), it says nothing about it being represented by a 1 byte integer.

Comment: There isn't, because a categorical dtype isn't treated the same as an int8 type. Toward the bottom of the docs they go through a whole list of problems caused by this distinction: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-is-not-a-numpy-array. The docs specifically call out **"Categoricals are not numeric data (even in the case that .categories is numeric)"**, so any dtype operation that implies such would be confusing.

Comment: ofc, you can write your own function to get the `.cat.codes.dtype` type as you suggest. and replace the pandas default to display it as `category`

Comment: @ALollz That's what I ended up doing (writing my own function). I was wondering if there was an easier way. Seems maybe not.

Answer (score 2):

for all columns data type you can use

```
dataframe.dtypes

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [True, False, False], 'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
print(df.dtypes)

A     int64                                                                                                                                                                                   
B      bool                                                                                                                                                                                   
C    object                                                                                                                                                                                   
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. For categorical columns, it will print `category` instead of printing something about the underlying representation for that categorical columns (linked to the number of bytes it uses).